# Return rows COUNT in Ionic 4

Tags: sql, angular, ionic-framework

I am working with Ionic app. I have SQLITE database. In the database I have table with name 'words'. Now I want to get how many rows I have in this table. I am using COUNT(*) SQL command which I think is right, because it's pretty easy, but I have problems with getting the number to my words.page.ts file, the function getWordsCount() is not working, it return [object Promise].

```
getWordsCount(){
  let count;
  count = this.database.executeSql("select count(*) from words", []);
  return count;
}
```

Actual result: [object Promise]

Expected result: any number ( 4 at this point)

Comment: use `async` `await` method

Answer (score 1):

The  `database.executeSql` method is a Promise. You have to wait till the promise get resolved to get the result.

```
async getWordsCount(){
  let count;
  count = await this.database.executeSql("select count(*) from words", []);
  return count;
}
```